# Uninstall cassandra from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, sudo

I want to uninstall cassandra from my PC(ubuntu 14.04). I run this command.

sudo apt-get remove cassandra

I got this error :-> **username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.**

Please help me to remove cassandra.

Comment: Have you tried with: sudo apt-get purge cassandra? The message indicates that your user doesn't have privileges.

Answer (score 4):

From the error you get, it appears that your user is not a sudo'er. What is the output of `groups`?

Your question is how to remove `cassandra`. If you have the password of `root` (if the root account is enabled), type

> su

Then type the password for `root`. Now you can delete `cassandra` via

> apt-get remove cassandra

If you do not have the password for root, you need to find a way to get access to `sudo` (and change your question accordingly).